# How can i make this "z-index" on Flutter, i try to use Stack

Tags: flutter

I need to make this [image: App-Stack]

[image: Same problem]
I tried so much but i cant get a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to follow the following tree

```
Stack [
Column ( max finit width and height ) [
 row { go back and menu buttons }
 row { with the border radius }
]
SizedBox ( fixed width and height postion to center ) [ 
 column [
 your balance text,
and the balance
]
]
```